# How to use request and path parameters in a Spring Boot REST controller?

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-restcontroller

I have the following upload controller which has two params with DIFFERENT type: 1
is for the path the file will be saved to and 2 the file itself. I'm looking
for the correct method definition instead of 2 @Requestparam which give error in STS.

```
@PostMapping("/{path}/")
public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("path"), @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    
    filesStorageService.store(file);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "You successfully uploaded " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!");
    
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Comment: for path you can use `@PathVariable("path") String path` as parameter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the [@PathVariable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html) annotation for the path parameter and add an additional argument (`String path`) to store it:

```
@PostMapping("/{path}/")
public String handleFileUpload(
   @PathVariable("path") String path,
   @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
   RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
   [...]
```